# Class inheritance with super - Getting through resolution order

Tags: python, oop

For this, I have been asked to find `d.m2(1)`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    
    def m1(self, x):
        return self.m2(x) - 2

    def m2(self, x):
        return 2*x

class B(A):
    def m1(self, y):
        return self._x + y
    
    def m2(self, y):
        self._y = y
        return self._x - self._y

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self._y = y
        self._x *= y

    def m1(self, x):
        return A.m2(self, x) + self._y

class D(C):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self._y = y + x
    
    def m2(self, y):
        return super().m2(y) + y

a = A(3)
b = B(1)
c = C(3, 2)
d = D(1, 2)
```

It's pretty confusing working my way through the method resolution order, but my logical approach must be wrong.

My thoughts are

1. We go to `m2` method class `D`. The `y` argument takes the value 1, and `super` returns us back to `m2` of class `A`, where we multiply `2 * 1 = 2`.
2. Back to `m2` of class `D`, and we return the `super().m2(y) + y` as `2 + 1` which is 3.

Except, the output is 2. Where am I going wrong here? For the `super().m2(y)`, are we going back to base class `A`, or is Python working through the order of inheritance back to where it can get to the first `m2` method, which is in class `B`?

Comment: Why do you think `super()` on instance of `D` goes to `A`?

Comment: @matszwecja my assumption was that as everything inherits from A, thats the base class and by default super will send everything back there. If it doesn't find it there, it would then go to parent class (C) of the child (D) it is currently working in. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect. A will only be used if nothing earlier in the chain matches. So, first you check in immediate parent of D (that is, C), then in parent of this parent etc. You can easily verify that by calling `.mro()` on the class object (`print(D.mro())`)

Comment: @matszwecja Awesome, great response, that helps a lot! Further quick question, if we had specified```class A (Object)``` at the top instead, would that change this MRO behaviour?

Comment: No, every class inherits from `object` by default

Comment: @matszwecja so if we did specify class A (Object) then super in class D WOULD then send it back to class A now, or would the same behaviour still apply?

Comment: No, `class A(object):` is the same as `class A:`.

Comment: Care to explain why you think it would?

Comment: Class inheritance is like an onion. Each layer wraps the one below it (above it in code). Any jumps between layers, like `super()`, just goes one layer down at a time. Did you look at `print(D.mro())`?

Comment: @quamrana yes I did, and now it makes much more sense when you can visualise whats happening. Thanks everyone for you help.